# How do align texts in the child div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to text-align to center on a div with texts. The texts inside the div needs to be aligned to the left.

In my jsfiddle

html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="texts">my text my text my text<br>my textmy text</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    text-align:center;
}

.texts{
   //not sure what to do    
}
```

I need to have texts div center inside the parent div but no indentations on two lines of texts. I can't really set the widths because they all needs to be responsive. How do I solve this? Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/bh4pu001/

Comment: use `.texts{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```css
.parent {
    text-align:center;
}

.texts{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="texts">my text my text my text<br>my textmy text</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set **display: inline-block;**

```
.texts{
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh4pu001/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Following code

```
.parent {
    float:left;
}

.texts{
    float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```css
.parent {
    float:left;
}

.texts{
    float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="texts">my text my text my text<br>my textmy text</div>    
</div>
```